# API endpoint: Receive post vars with $_POST or file_get_contents('php://input')?

Tags: php, json, api

I'm working on an API endpoint that receives notifications when payments have gone through. The gateway I'm currently implementing is a chilean bank transfer gateway called Khipu. When they send the notification, I have to receive the POST variables using `$_POST` as opposed to `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))`. It seems Khipu handles `POST`s in a way that's a bit unconventional, no? What is the difference between how Khipu does it, and all others? How is Khipu sending these `POST` vars? Why do I have to receive the variables from them using `$_POST`? To avoid any problem in retrieving variables, I'm using the following code, which seems to work fine:

```
if (empty($_POST)) { //For strange posts used by Khipu
    $postVars = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
} else {
    $postVars = $_POST;
}
```

Comment: `file_get_contents('php://input')` does not return the post parameters but it reads the data stream of the request body. `$_POST` contains the post parameters in case the POST wrapper knows how to handle to data type. This explains it quite clear: https://codehunter.cc/a/php/php-php-input-vs-post

Comment: [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is very different from HTML form encoding. $_POST is only populated if your server receives form-encoded data. Khipu sends JSON, not form-encoded data. JSON is very common for machine-to-machine communication nowadays.